# Accurately determining CPU usage per process

Tags: windows, performance, cpu-usage

I'm writing a program that needs to know how much CPU time each process is using to a reasonable accuracy.  As accurate as Task Manager or Process Explorer is fine.

Using Kernel32 [GetProcessTimes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683223(v=vs.85).aspx) results in poor accuracy.  For processes that consume little CPU time, the difference between two calls is often 0 (even when measured over a period of several seconds).  Both Task Manager and Process Explorer however give a much more accurate measurement showing that the process infact did consume *some* cpu time during my measuring interval.

This inaccuracy with GetProcessTimes is apparently because:

1. It only counts time slices that were fully used
2. The time slice as used by the Windows scheduler seems to be 15.625 ms (1/64th of a second) which is an eternity...

I've been looking into using the function [QueryProcessCycleTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684929(v=vs.85).aspx), mainly because Process Explorer is displaying the number of cycles used when you look at a process' properties performance tab.  Even in Process Explorer the "Time" counters seem to have a 15 ms resolution, but the cycles counter seems to have a much higher resolution (in other words, it doesn't count up with some fixed number like 15.625 ms).

My problem however is that I cannot find any information on how to relate the number of processor cycles to actual time spent.  There is no function to get the total number of processor cycles (that I'm aware of) -- and with frequency scaling and low power modes this could very tricky -- the only option I see there would be to sum all cycles from all processes (which requires Administrative privileges to get those for System processes) to get the total, which would then allow me to calculate the CPU used by a single process...

So, does anyone have insights on how Task Manager / Process Explorer accomplish their accurate CPU % measurements, or any other options I could explore to get accurate CPU times?

Comment: The default clock resolution for MS Windows is 15.625 ms. You can always check it via clockres.exe utility out of SysInternals pack. Some apps do lower resolution like MS Visual Studio and Google Chrome browser for better performance, but it is bad decision for a long time to play, especially on laptops on a battery. (A scandal occurs back in the days, and they did not fix it yet!) The minimum time interval possible for desktop user apps is 0.500 ms. Maybe kernel mode driver could force is better, I'm not sure.

Comment: @84RR1573R That isn't even remotely true.  In win32 `QueryPerformanceCounter` provides far higher accuracy and in Java there is  `System.nanoTime` which also provides far higher accuracy even on Windows.  Unfortunately those all measure wall-clock time.  Of course you donot want to play with the scheduler time slice, but you don't need to just to get accurate timings...

Comment: "provides far higher accuracy even on Windows" is obvious because java.exe as well as the whole Oracle's and IBM JVM is written on C++ and compiled with MS Visual Studio 2010 (yes, not the fresh one) compiler using the same system libraries like any other user mode app. So it won't be any faster or slower in execution. All you need is to find out how to call the proper functions or maybe redesign your app. I think I had some source codes of SysInternals utilities but I'm not sure there was Process Explorer. I need to track it down.